# File inclusion with angle brackets searches directory of current file first

Tags: c, macos, homebrew

I have an issue on macOS with Homebrew where the inclusion of a system header results in the inclusion of a header file in the directory of the current file with the same name despite using angle brackets in the include directive. Here is a minimal example which illustrates the problem:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <time.h>

time_t someTime;

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
$ cat time.h
$ gcc test.c 
test.c:3:1: error: unknown type name 'time_t'
    3 | time_t someTime;
      | ^~~~~~
test.c:2:1: note: 'time_t' is defined in header '<time.h>'; did you forget to '#include <time.h>'?
    1 | #include <time.h>
  +++ |+#include <time.h>
    2 |
```

According to *The C Programming Language*

> if the name is enclosed in `<` and `>`, searching follows an implementation-defined rule to find the file.

I was under the impression that the directory of the current file is not searched when angle brackets are used or at least not before the system paths are searched. Is this how it should be on macOS or is something badly configured?

Comment: Is there a `time.h` file in the same directory as your `test.c` source file?

Comment: It's a bad idea to reuse filenames of system header files for other things.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I wrote the wrong cat command. Fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffHolt I agree. I was just surprised to see it failing on macOS when it works on Linux.

Comment: Perhaps it's a homebrew issue, where there is no system `time.h` installed, and the compiler fall back to your local file?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The system header time.h is there and my example works if the local time.h is deleted.

Comment: What is the actual compiler that HomeBrew uses, or that you are using? According to the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html), the `<...>` syntax should *not* first look in the current directory. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593/10871073

Comment: Use the `-v` (verbose) option of GCC to see the full and complete search path for header files.

Comment: POSIX says that [`c99`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html) must follow a particular search pattern: _Change the algorithm for searching for headers whose names are not absolute pathnames to look in the directory named by the directory pathname before looking in the usual places. Thus, headers whose names are enclosed in double-quotes (`""`) shall be searched for first in the directory of the file with the `#include` line, then in directories named in `-I` options, and last in the usual places._ […continued…]_

Comment: […continuation…] _For headers whose names are enclosed in angle brackets (`<>`), the header shall be searched for only in directories named in `-I` options and then in the usual places. Directories named in `-I` options shall be searched in the order specified. If the `-I` option is used to specify a directory that is one of the usual places searched by default, the results are unspecified._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It wouldn't surprise me if Homebrew is adding `-I.` or some equivalent.  The question definitely needs to add the actual compiler in use *and* the full command line used to invoke the compilation step.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Running the C compiler with the -v option shows that the current directory is indeed searched fist (see my answer). Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: How is POSIX relevant? macOS as initially installed might be POSIX compliant, but OP installed something with Homebrew, possibly GCC, and who knows how they configured it? There is no guarantee your environment is POSIX-compliant after you have tinkered with it.

Comment: Re “I have an issue on macOS with Homebrew… `$ gcc test.c`”: How is an issue you encounter with the `gcc` command an issue with Homebrew? Did you install GCC using Homebrew? Or did you encounter this issue while trying to use Homebrew to install something, and it used `gcc` and encountered this error? Give enough information for other people to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By running `clang -v test.c` you will get output where the relevant part is

```
...
#include <...> search starts here:
.
/opt/homebrew/include
/opt/homebrew/include/pango-1.0
...
```

This means that the current directory (.) is indeed searched first. The solution is to avoid the name clash by renaming time.h.